# Whats happening when jq commands are used without quotes?

Tags: json, bash, jq

This is my data file: `explorejq.json` -

```
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "data": {
        "app.properties": "some.base64encoded.data"
    },
    "kind": "ConfigMap",
    "metadata": {
        "creationTimestamp": "2021-05-17T09:54:15Z",
        "name": "myappproperties",
        "namespace": "myappnamespace",
        "resourceVersion": "352258550",
        "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/myappnamespace/configmap/myappproperties",
        "uid": "cb23197e-54ee-412a-a07a-7d02df3d59a1"
    },
    "type": "IncorrectType"
}
```

And i want to retrive the value of key `app.properties` which is nested in `data`. I know the right way of doing this is using -
`cat explorejq.json |  jq '.data ' | jq '.["app.properties"]'` or
`cat explorejq.json |  jq '.data | .["app.properties"]'`  and i get
output:   `"some.base64encoded.data"`    as required

**Now the problem is one of my fellow developer is using jq commands without single quotes for the last part.  Example -**
`cat explorejq.json |  jq '.data ' | jq .["app.properties"]`  or
`cat explorejq.json |  jq '.data ' | jq .[".app.properties"]`    or
`cat explorejq.json |  jq '.data ' | jq .["., ., app.properties"]`    and getting
output -

```
{
  "app.properties": "some.base64encoded.data"
}
"some.base64encoded.data"
```

Now, i know all the above three are incorrect ways, but i need to understand whats happening in these cases so i can explain the same.

Can someone explain what happens when jq commands are used without single quote and particularly whats happening in above cases.

**Edit -**
Basically the issue here is with `jq .["app.properties"]`. Shell is interpreting it before passing it to jq.
`echo jq .["., ., app.properties"]` output: `jq ..`.
Same is the case with rest of the two patterns i mentioned.

So posted a new Q here - [what is .. (two dots) in jq filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70489706/what-is-two-dots-in-jq-filter)

Comment: if i can i will rather try to simplify this Q with out shell involvemnt and repost it. I can't remove/delete this as it has answers. Editing it would make the answers look out of context and confuse future readers.

Comment: i see this is not jq issue. This about what shell is passing to jq.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, also `cat explorejq.json |  jq '.data ' | jq '."app.properties"'` would work (or simplified to `jq '.data."app.properties"' explorejq.json`). The relevant part is that `"app.properties"` is surrounded by quotes as it needs to be a JSON string (within jq). In turn, the whole jq filter is also a string for the calling environment (within the shell). That's why you also need to quote the filter (if it contains spaces, quotes etc). However, as it contains double quotes for the JSON string, single quotes are the appropriate choice for the jq filter string. If you did't use those outer quotes, the shell would interpret itself the inner ones as string boundaries and as such they wouldn't appear in the actual jq filter anymore. As a consequence, jq would fail in rendering `app.properties` as actual JSON string.

Comment: well this is quite simplified - `jq '.data."app.properties"' explorejq.json` ++1

Answer (score 1):

The string quotes are part of bash scripting and are needed if you want to pass an argument that contains spaces to a command. In your case the arguments does not contain spaces, so no quotes are needed to pass `.["app.properties"]` as argument to `jq`.

In the last case bash concatenates one string with two spaces `.["., ., app.properties"]` that is passed to `jq` as *one* argument.

So your fellow developer is doing everything right ;-)
Although I myself also find it clearer to use simple quotes for the entire jq program.

Comment: could you explain - why this case is failing(i mean giving more output then exptected)  `cat explorejq.json |  jq '.data ' | jq .["app.properties"]` / ++1

Comment: When calling `jq .["app.properties"]` you tell your shell to call jq with the argument `.["app.properties"]`. As the argument is not a literal string (it is not surrounded by quotes) it is first interpreted by the shell as `..` (Try running `echo .["app.properties"]` to see it). So, the call is actually ``jq '..'``, with `..` as the jq filter string. Then, jq interprets `..` as the [recursive descent](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#RecursiveDescent:..) operator, producing every value it finds, which, given its input, is the object containing the value and the value itself.

Answer (score 1):

You've already figured out that the shell is processing `.["., ., app.properties"]` into `..` but you may not have figured out why yet.

Unquoted square brackets are [pattern-matching syntax for a single character](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13_01), similar to the way `?` is a wildcard for any single character and `*` is a wildcard for zero or more characters. In this case, you've created a pattern-match for any file with a name starting with `.` and followed by any single character from the set `., ., app.properties` which simplifies to the set `., aeioprst`. Since `..` is present in every directory, it always matches and you get `..`. However, if for example you had a file called `.p` in the current directory, it would match too and you'd send an extra argument to `jq`. The immediate lesson of the story is always single-quote your filter argument to `jq`. The broader moral is that it's hard to learn and remember all the shell rules and behaviours, but it's much easier to remember a safe subset. If you know that single quotes pass the entire argument through verbatim, and if you stick to them for any argument containing characters you're unsure might have special behaviour, you don't need to worry about all the things you don't know.

Comment: this is superb. But i did after lot of struggle figure it out. Shell is cool and so is your deeper analysis. ++1. Could you upvote the Q if you like it.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take advantage of the `-f` option of jq, where you can put your filter program in a file, and have jq read it from the file. This saves you from the hassles of shell quoting.

Comment: well said. could you upvote the Q if you like. ++1

Answer (score 1):

First of all,

```sh
cat explorejq.json | jq '.data ' | jq '.["app.properties"]'
```

is better written as one of the following:

```sh
jq '.data.["app.properties"]' explorejq.json
```

```sh
jq '.data."app.properties"' explorejq.json
```

To keep things simple, I'll be using the first of those commands as the example in the rest of the post.

---

The following is the jq program you want to execute:

```
.data.["app.properties"]
```

So you want to devise a shell command that passes that string as an argument.

Because `"` is special to the shell, this won't do:

```sh
jq .data.["app.properties"]      # XXX Passes `.data.[app.properties]`
```

You need to employ some form of quoting or escaping. The following are two options:

```sh
jq '.data.["app.properties"]'    # Ok. Passes `.data.["app.properties"]`
```

```sh
jq .data.[\"app.properties\"]    # Ok. Passes `.data.["app.properties"]`
```

---

Quoting tips:

If it doesn't contain single quotes (`'`), you can simply wrap the argument in single quotes.

If it does contain single quotes (`'`), you can simply wrap the argument in single quotes, plus replace each existing `'` with `'\''`.

Comment: cool - `If it does contain single quotes ('), you can simply wrap the argument in single quotes, plus replace each existing ' with '\''` ++1

Comment: would you mind upvoting the Q.