# what is .. (two dots) in jq filter

Tags: jq

given my input file: kind.json

```
[
  {
    "kind": "ConfigMap1"
  },
  {
    "kind": "ConfigMap1"
  },
  {
    "kind": "ConfigMap2"
  },
  {
    "kind": "ConfigMap'4"
  },
  {
    "kind": "ConfigMap\"6"
  }
]
```

and on using jq command `jq .. kind.json`, i am seeing unexpected output. You can see that here -> https://jqplay.org/s/pTe-CtdXV1.

```
[
  {
    "kind": "ConfigMap1"
  },
  {
    "kind": "ConfigMap1"
  },
  {
    "kind": "ConfigMap2"
  },
  {
    "kind": "ConfigMap'4"
  },
  {
    "kind": "ConfigMap\"6"
  }
]
{
  "kind": "ConfigMap1"
}
"ConfigMap1"
{
  "kind": "ConfigMap1"
}
"ConfigMap1"
{
  "kind": "ConfigMap2"
}
"ConfigMap2"
{
  "kind": "ConfigMap'4"
}
"ConfigMap'4"
{
  "kind": "ConfigMap\"6"
}
"ConfigMap\"6"
```

Just wondering what the two dots mean here and what jq is doing here. Any help and explanation will be greatly appriciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is the [recursive descent](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#RecursiveDescent:..) operator `..`. Starting from the input, it recursively descends and produces every value it can find.

First, you see the whole input (the array), then each member of the array (the objects), and after each of them all field values within an object (the strings).

Comment: To filter by type, try out the filters [`.. | arrays`](https://jqplay.org/s/w8Tw_neSjo), [`.. | objects`](https://jqplay.org/s/1ZGcjIAHDU) or [`.. | strings`](https://jqplay.org/s/v1TJ7nKmWd).